# view taking over 3 mins to load

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, nhibernate, code-first

Using asp.net MVC 4.0 c#, Visual Studio 2012 professional.

Ok i have a single action result in my controller, the purpose is to take a number of different services and models, and to de-normalize the data into a list for the view to display, this is based on user interaction via simple control's used to filter the data.

The whole site has been migrated from a Webforms Sql project, to a MVC code first approach using an in house CMS solution (cms is based on Nop commerce and Orchard).

now this controller function was working fairly ok until I added in the code for each module passed.  I originally wanted to do the same as i did with the old project, join the data then cross query for de-normalized results to be then used.

however as I'm transferring from SQL to code first I wasnt sure if or how i could mimic a cross query.

This resulted in me creating a lot of loops.
here's the controller action method and non action.

```
 public ActionResult Index(UsersModel model) 
    {
        model.DateTo = model.DateTo.AddDays(1);

        if (model.DateFrom == null || model.DateTo == null || model.DateFrom == DateTime.MinValue || model.DateTo == DateTime.MinValue.AddDays(1))
        {
            // default to last 30 days
            model.DateFrom = _clock.UtcNow.AddDays(-30);
            model.DateTo = _clock.UtcNow;
        }

        var userQuery = _academyUserService.Query()
            .Where(x => x.Activity.DateRegistered >= model.DateFrom && x.Activity.DateRegistered <= model.DateTo);

        var quizCompletedQuery = _quizService.QueryQuizHistoryCompleted()
            .Where(x => x.DateCompleted >= model.DateFrom && x.DateCompleted <= model.DateTo);

        var quizHistoryQuery = _quizService.QueryHistory()
            .Where(x => x.DateCompleted >= model.DateFrom && x.DateCompleted <= model.DateTo);

        var moduleQuery = _moduleService.Query()
            .Where(x => x.Published);

        //admin country selected, null = global
        if (_moServices.WorkContext.HttpContext.Session["AdminAreaCurrentCulture"] != null)
        {
            userQuery = userQuery.Where(x => x.UserCountry.CountryCulture.Culture == _moServices.WorkContext.HttpContext.Session["AdminAreaCurrentCulture"].ToString());
            quizCompletedQuery = quizCompletedQuery.Where(x => x.Country.CountryCulture.Culture == _moServices.WorkContext.HttpContext.Session["AdminAreaCurrentCulture"].ToString());
            quizHistoryQuery = quizHistoryQuery.Where(x => x.Module.Country.CountryCulture.Culture == _moServices.WorkContext.HttpContext.Session["AdminAreaCurrentCulture"].ToString());
            moduleQuery = moduleQuery.Where(x => x.Country.CountryCulture.Culture == _moServices.WorkContext.HttpContext.Session["AdminAreaCurrentCulture"].ToString());
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Name))
        {
            userQuery = userQuery.Where(x => x.FirstName.Contains(model.Name) || x.Surname.Contains(model.Name));
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.AccountType))
        {
            userQuery = userQuery.Where(x => x.AccountType.ToString() == model.AccountType);
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Company))
        {
            userQuery = userQuery.Where(x => x.BusinessName == model.Company);//placeholder intefering with this?
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Code))
        {
            userQuery = userQuery.Where(x => x.RegistrationCode.Contains(model.Code));
        }

        if(true)//cant condition an Iquery as its not a list...)//temp
        {
            //quizCompletedQuery = quizCompletedQuery.Where(x => x.Country.CountryCulture.Culture == _moServices.WorkContext.HttpContext.Session["AdminAreaCurrentCulture"].ToString());
        }

        //new code
        var groupedModules = moduleQuery
             .OrderBy(x => x.DisplayOrder)
             .ToList()
             .GroupBy(x => x.Country)
             .SelectMany(group => group.Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Module = x }))
             .GroupBy(anon => anon.Index)
             .Select(group => group.Select(x => x.Module).ToList())
             .ToList();

        var historyResults = quizHistoryQuery.ToList();

        //my old code
        PrepareBusinessNames(model);

        var usersToModel = userQuery.ToList().Select(x =>
        {

            bool thisHistoryPassed1 = false;
            bool thisHistoryPassed2 = false;
            bool thisHistoryPassed3 = false;
            bool thisHistoryPassed4 = false;

            if (groupedModules.Count > 0)
            {
                var module1 = groupedModules[0];
                var moduleIds1 = module1.Select(y => y.Id).ToList();
                var thisHistory1 = quizHistoryQuery.Where(y => y.User.Id == x.Id && moduleIds1.Contains(y.Module.Id));
                thisHistoryPassed1 = thisHistory1.Any(_quizService.IsHistoryPassed);
            }

            if (groupedModules.Count > 1)
            {
                var module2 = groupedModules[1];
                var moduleIds2 = module2.Select(y => y.Id).ToList();
                var thisHistory2 = quizHistoryQuery.Where(y => y.User.Id == x.Id && moduleIds2.Contains(y.Module.Id));
                thisHistoryPassed2 = thisHistory2.Any(_quizService.IsHistoryPassed);
            }

            if (groupedModules.Count > 2)
            {
                var module3 = groupedModules[2];
                var moduleIds3 = module3.Select(y => y.Id).ToList();
                var thisHistory3 = quizHistoryQuery.Where(y => y.User.Id == x.Id && moduleIds3.Contains(y.Module.Id));
                thisHistoryPassed3 = thisHistory3.Any(_quizService.IsHistoryPassed);
            }

            if (groupedModules.Count > 3)
            {
                var module4 = groupedModules[3];
                var moduleIds4 = module4.Select(y => y.Id).ToList();
                var thisHistory4 = quizHistoryQuery.Where(y => y.User.Id == x.Id && moduleIds4.Contains(y.Module.Id));
                thisHistoryPassed4 = thisHistory4.Any(_quizService.IsHistoryPassed);
            }

            return new UsersSearchModel
            {
                UserID = x.Id,
                Name = x.FirstName,
                Surname = x.Surname,
                Company = x.BusinessName,
                AccountType = x.AccountType.ToString(),
                UserCode = x.RegistrationCode,
                VideosViewed = "", //x.VideoActivity.ToString(), 
                Module1 = thisHistoryPassed1,
                Module2 = thisHistoryPassed2,
                Module3 = thisHistoryPassed3,
                Module4 = thisHistoryPassed4,
                Module1Url = thisHistoryPassed1 ? Url.Content("~/Areas/Admin/Media/Images/checked.png") : Url.Content("~/Areas/Admin/Media/Images/unchecked.png"),
                Module2Url = thisHistoryPassed2 ? Url.Content("~/Areas/Admin/Media/Images/checked.png") : Url.Content("~/Areas/Admin/Media/Images/unchecked.png"),
                Module3Url = thisHistoryPassed3 ? Url.Content("~/Areas/Admin/Media/Images/checked.png") : Url.Content("~/Areas/Admin/Media/Images/unchecked.png"),
                Module4Url = thisHistoryPassed4 ? Url.Content("~/Areas/Admin/Media/Images/checked.png") : Url.Content("~/Areas/Admin/Media/Images/unchecked.png")
            };
        }).ToList();

        var jsonSerialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var jsonString = jsonSerialiser.Serialize(usersToModel);//or is it model? or a list of model?
        model.REFACTOR_ForJson = jsonString;

        return View(model);
    }

    #region utilities

    [NonAction]
    private UsersModel PrepareBusinessNames(UsersModel model)
    {
        if (_moServices.Authoriser.Authorise(DefaultPermissions.AccessAdminPanel))
        {
            var listItems = _academyUserService.GetAllBusinessNames().Select(x =>
            {
                return new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = x,
                    Text = x
                };
            }).OrderBy(x => x.Value)
            .ToList();

            model.CurrentBusinessNames = new SelectList(listItems, "Value", "Text");
        }

        return model;
    }
```

as you can see I want to return a list of users and based on filters display that list with 4 columns representing the modules and if passed or not.

As i have said, when i added the code to get the boolean values for the passed or not passed, my query has been shot and takes far to long.

so, is there a way to fix the issue via tweak of existing code or, is the solution to rewrite the functionality possibly using a similar method to that of a cross query?

thanks for your tips guys!

Update::

heres the profile result, as I have never used this before im not sure what Im looking at here.

[image: Profile]

Commented out the part "if(groupedModules.Count > 0)" and the other If statements, this definatly sems to be the cause of the major slow response.  So as I have asked before, is there a better way to achieve my results?

update:: replaced

```
if (groupedModules.Count > 0)
            {
                var module1 = groupedModules[0];
                var moduleIds1 = module1.Select(y => y.Id).ToList();
                var thisHistory1 = quizHistoryQuery.Where(y => y.User.Id == x.Id && moduleIds1.Contains(y.Module.Id));
                thisHistoryPassed1 = thisHistory1.Any(_quizService.IsHistoryPassed);
            }
```

to

```
if (groupedModules.Count > 0)
            {
                var module1 = groupedModules[0];
                var moduleIds1 = module1.Select(y => y.Id).ToList();
                var thisHistory1 = historyResults.Where(y => y.User.Id == x.Id && moduleIds1.Contains(y.Module.Id));
                thisHistoryPassed1 = thisHistory1.Any(_quizService.IsHistoryPassed);
            }
```

instead of using the iquerable, i tolist the history then use the list instead.
this significantly reduces time to load, from 6mins to 15 seconds.
However as you all know this is still far to slow, the only conclusion is the fact this code must lie in the select list.  So is there a way to redo the process?

Comment: yeh my first thign was to remove the tolist, however this made 0 improvement, i left this in as it was added by the lead over the weekend.

Comment: Have you tried using any actual performance measurement tools on this? Have the queries been profiled using SQL Profiler and external tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick guess: the data is still in query-form when you're performing the group query. GroupBy() on EF has such horrible performance that it's far faster to force it to list first.

Long answer which is far shorter than the quick guess: Profile!

Comment: yeh i heard this too, although didnt see an impact on my page time.  this is basically when i put in the code for the modules, all of a sudden it just ground to a near stop, could it be a combination of this and my repeated looping of the modules?

Comment: Seriously, profile! It's not hard or scary :). If you're using Visual Studio, you find it under Analyse. If you don't profile, you're likely to start chasing ghosts. If you do, you'll instantly know where the problem is. If that doesn't give you your solution straight away, you can ask the more focused why could x be slow, rather than which part of the whole story might be causing it.

Comment: By the profiler screenshot it appears the OP is in fact using NHibernate and not EF.

Comment: Yeah, it's clearly something NHibernate is doing. I don't know NHibernate though, so I have no idea. Following the hot path in the profile trace is probably a good idea - it'll lead you to the parts of your code that are being problematic.

Answer (score 1):

```
var historyResults = quizHistoryQuery.ToList();
```

it seems you are executing this query and storing the results in a list yet a few lines bellow you are doing:

```
var thisHistory1 = quizHistoryQuery.Where(y => y.User.Id == x.Id && moduleIds1.Contains(y.Module.Id));
```

causing the query to be executed again.

This is just something that popped out and i have no idea if it's causing your slowdown. Anyway please recheck any instances where you might run the same query twice because it appears you are doing this in a couple of places. Consider storing the results in lists and working with them from then on.
Also consider starting up SQL Profiler and see how your generated SQL queries look and which one takes the most time.

Comment: quick update, took out the history results (old redundant code i think) but has made 0 difference, still looking